How to implement a search bar for my endpoints using Swagger-UI with drf-spectacular?
I am using the drf-spectacular library together with Swagger-UI to document my Django Rest views.
I want to have a search bar displayed in Swagger-UI where the user can search for a specific endpoint using the displayed endpoint urls. I tried the filter option of Swagger-UI settings but it would not search anything except for the endpoints default tag (which is the django app name). It does not search any other text in the endpoint url.
